# @firebase/util version issue

Tags: angular, firebase, npm

I'm now trying to update firebase in my app.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/fire": "6.1.4",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "11.0.0-beta.33",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.10",
    "@mdi/angular-material": "5.9.55",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@types/gapi": "0.0.39",
    "@types/gapi.auth2": "0.0.54",
    "angular-split": "5.0.0",
    "firebase": "8.4.1",
    "lodash-es": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1100.7",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "11.2.9",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "1.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "1.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.10",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "14.14.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "9.10.0",
    "fuzzy": "0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "7.3.3",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "1.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "7.4.2",
    "protractor": "7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "8.3.0",
    "typescript": "4.0.5"
  }
}
```

I removed `node_modules` and executed `npm install`. Then I tried `npm list --depth=0` and produced the error below.

```
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @firebase/util@0.x, required by @firebase/auth-types@0.10.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @firebase/util@0.x, required by @firebase/auth-interop-types@0.1.5
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @firebase/util@1.x, required by @firebase/storage-types@0.4.0
```

Required `@firebase/util` version mismatches. The `@firebase/auth-types` and `@firebase/auth-interop-types` require `0.x` but `@firebase/storage-types` requires `1.x`.

How should I fix this?

Comment: I expect this is going to be a similar issue to what I ran into today with firebase / firebase-admin. Seems they are working on updating the dependencies there (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/1241), perhaps firebase-tools will need a similar fix? Perhaps you should report it at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose ?